# java 8 merge all elements of ListB into ListA if not present

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I need to merge all elements of a **listB** into another list **listA**.

If an element is already present (based on a custom equality-check) in **listA** I don't want to add it.

I don't want to use Set, and I don't want to override equals() and hashCode().

Reasons are, I don't want to prevent duplicates in listA per se, I only want to not merge from listB if there are already elements in listA which I consider being equal.

I don't want to override equals() and hashCode() since that would mean I need to make sure, my implementation of equals() for the elements hold in every circumstance. It might however be, that elements from listB are not fully initialized, i.e. they might miss an object id, where that might be present in elements of listA.

My current approach involves an interface and a Utility-Function:

```java
public interface HasEqualityFunction<T> {

    public boolean hasEqualData(T other);
}

public class AppleVariety implements HasEqualityFunction<AppleVariety> {
    private String manufacturerName;
    private String varietyName;

    @Override
    public boolean hasEqualData(AppleVariety other) {
        return (this.manufacturerName.equals(other.getManufacturerName())
            && this.varietyName.equals(other.getVarietyName()));
    }

    // ... getter-Methods here
}


public class CollectionUtils {
    public static <T extends HasEqualityFunction> void merge(
        List<T> listA,
        List<T> listB) {
        if (listB.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        Predicate<T> exists
            = (T x) -> {
                return listA.stream().noneMatch(
                        x::hasEqualData);
            };
        listA.addAll(listB.stream()
            .filter(exists)
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
        );
    }
}
```

And then I'd use it like this:

```java
...
List<AppleVariety> appleVarietiesFromOnePlace = ... init here with some elements
List<AppleVariety> appleVarietiesFromAnotherPlace = ... init here with some elements
CollectionUtils.merge(appleVarietiesFromOnePlace, appleVarietiesFromAnotherPlace);
...
```

to get my new list in listA with all elements merged from B.

Is this a good approach? Is there a better/easier way to accomplish the same?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
public static <T> void merge(List<T> listA, List<T> listB, BiPredicate<T, T> areEqual) {
    listA.addAll(listB.stream()
                      .filter(t -> listA.stream().noneMatch(u -> areEqual.test(t, u)))
                      .collect(Collectors.toList())
    );
}
```

You don't need a `HasEqualityFunction` interface. You can reuse `BiPredicate` to test whether the two objects are equal with regard to your logic.

This code filters only the elements in `listB` which are not contained in `listA` as per the predicate given. It does traverse `listA` as many times as there are elements in `listB`.

---

An alternative and better performant implementation would be to use a wrapper class that wraps your elements and has as `equals` method your predicate:

```
public static <T> void merge(List<T> listA, List<T> listB, BiPredicate<T, T> areEqual, ToIntFunction<T> hashFunction) {

    class Wrapper {
        final T wrapped;
        Wrapper(T wrapped) {
            this.wrapped = wrapped;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            return areEqual.test(wrapped, ((Wrapper) obj).wrapped);
        }
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return hashFunction.applyAsInt(wrapped);
        }
    }

    Set<Wrapper> wrapSet = listA.stream().map(Wrapper::new).collect(Collectors.toSet());

    listA.addAll(listB.stream()
                      .filter(t -> !wrapSet.contains(new Wrapper(t)))
                      .collect(Collectors.toList())
    );
}
```

This first wraps every element inside a `Wrapper` object and collects them into a `Set`. Then, it filters the elements of `listB` that are not contained in this set. The equality test is done by delegating to the given predicate. The constraint is that we also need to give a `hashFunction` to properly implement `hashCode`.

Sample code would be:

```
List<String> listA = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "test"));
List<String> listB = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("toto", "foobar"));
CollectionUtils.merge(listA, listB, (s1, s2) -> s1.length() == s2.length(), String::length);
System.out.println(listA);
```

Comment: Thanks, I already applied your suggestion with the BiPredicate and eliminated the Interface. I'll also look into your 2nd suggestion later - using a wrapper class to be able to override equals and hashCode in a specific context is a great idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [HashingStrategy](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/7.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/block/HashingStrategy.html) based `Set` from [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/)

If you can use [MutableList](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) interface:

```
public static void merge(MutableList<AppleVariety> listA, MutableList<AppleVariety> listB)
{
    MutableSet<AppleVariety> hashingStrategySet = HashingStrategySets.mutable.withAll(
        HashingStrategies.fromFunctions(AppleVariety::getManufacturerName,
            AppleVariety::getVarietyName), 
        listA);   
    listA.addAllIterable(listB.asLazy().reject(hashingStrategySet::contains));
}
```

If you can't change the type of listA and listB from `List`:

```
public static void merge(List<AppleVariety> listA, List<AppleVariety> listB)
{
    MutableSet<AppleVariety> hashingStrategySet = HashingStrategySets.mutable.withAll(
        HashingStrategies.fromFunctions(AppleVariety::getManufacturerName,
            AppleVariety::getVarietyName), 
        listA);
    listA.addAll(ListAdapter.adapt(listB).reject(hashingStrategySet::contains));
}
```

Note: I am a contributor to Eclipse Collections.